# login via html - specifically to reddit.com

Tags: html, authentication, https, reddit

I have been trying to login to reddit via URL without much luck, so I have tried with an HTML file.  My main goal is to have a one click login to reddit, without cookies.

I searched the reddit source code to try and find the correct names for password and username, maybe I'm using the wrong ones in my HTML or this just isn't possible with html.

Any thoughts on fixing this html?

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Automatic Login</title>
</head>
<body onload="document.forms['securelog'].submit();">
    <form action="https://pay.reddit.com" method="post" name="securelog">
        <input type="hidden" name="user*" value="redditboy">
        <input type="hidden" name="passwd*" value="mypass1">

        <!--I have tried user_reg passwd_reg also but they didnt work-->

    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: I think that it is `user` and `passwd` (without the '*'?).  [Src](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/280eebc2a1150ebfb38d5d98e10db0abbd133ff6/r2/r2/controllers/api.py#L615).  Also, I don't think you need to be using `pay.reddit.com`, as HTTPS is now supported sitewide and has been a while.  In fact, I think the main issue is that you are posting to the root site, instead of the login endpoint.  Try `action="https://www.reddit.com/login"`.  ([Src on login](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/blob/9372deb62f057a1d504b7722fb54adfad9c2cd53/r2/r2/config/routing.py#L64))

Comment: If that works, let me know and I'll post a full answer.

Comment: Thanks @Pokechu22 but it didnt't work, it returned page not found.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be able to successfully submit a form from another site to reddit.com, because that would be a [CSRF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) attack.

What are you actually trying to do?  You probably want to use [OAuth](https://github.com/reddit/reddit/wiki/OAuth2).